# unneccesary padding on top and bottom of cardview in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a cardview in a recyclerview and the problem I am facing is that on populating the recyclerview unneccessary padding appears on top and bottom of imageview inside the cardview.The code of the recyclerview row is given below[image: screenshot].please help me
I have tried a lot of codes on stack but no use

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/productsearch_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/productsearch"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Proin Volutpat Purus."
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:scaleY="1.2"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="$"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolorpink"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prodprice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="25"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolorpink"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add

> android:adjustViewBounds="true"

to the ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/productsearch_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/productsearch"/>
```

P.S. Why do you use LinearLayout for ImageView, you can remove it. It's an unnecessary nesting